# Shortest way to form a string out of a subsequence of a string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, strings, ecmascript-6

**The task** is [taken from LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-way-to-form-string/) (subscription required) -

> From any string, we can form a subsequence of that string by deleting
> some number of characters (possibly no deletions).
>
> Given two strings source and target, return the minimum number of
> subsequences of source such that their concatenation equals target. If
> the task is impossible, return `-1`.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: source = "abc", target = "abcbc"
> Output: 2
> // Explanation: The target "abcbc" can be formed by "abc" and "bc", which are subsequences of source "abc".
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: source = "abc", target = "acdbc"
> Output: -1
> // Explanation: The target string cannot be constructed from the subsequences of source string due to the character "d" in target
> // string.
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: source = "xyz", target = "xzyxz"
> Output: 3
> // Explanation: The target string can be constructed as follows "xz" + "y" + "xz".
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> Both the source and target strings consist of only lowercase English
> letters from "a"-"z". The lengths of source and target string are
> between 1 and 1000.

**My solution** has space complexity of \$O(n)\$ and time complexity of \$O(n^2)\$ (I think...)

```
/**
 * @param {string} source
 * @param {string} target
 * @return {number}
 */
var shortestWay = function(source, target) {
    const map = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (map.get(source[i])) {
            const arr = map.get(source[i]);
            arr.push(i);
            map.set(source[i], arr);            
        } else {
            map.set(source[i], [i]);
        }
    }
    let occurrences = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        const indexes = map.get(target[i]);
        if (indexes === void 0) return -1;
        occurrences++;
        let max = 0;
        indexes.forEach(index => {
            let j = 0;
            let ignore = 0;
            while(source[index + j + ignore] !== void 0) {
                if(target[i + j] !== source[index + j + ignore]) {
                    ignore++;
                } else {
                    max = Math.max(max, j++);
                }
            }
        });
        i += max;
    }
    return occurrences;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is `O(n^2*m)`, where `n` is the target and `m` is the source. Overall, though, I think there are a lot of readability improvements that could be made here by separating functions and renaming variables (`j` is a particularly bad contender).

```
// indexCharacters('hello')
// = {'h':[0],'e':[1],'l':[2,3],'o':[4]}
const indexCharacters = source => {
    const map = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        const char = source[i];
        if (!map.get(char)) map.set(char,[]);
        map.get(char).push(i);
    }
    return map;
}

// matchLength('abc','abeee') = 2
const matchLength = (source,target) => {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i=0;i<source.length;++i)
        if (target[count] === source[i])
            ++count;
    return count;
}

const shortestWay = (source, target) => {
    const all_character_indices = indexCharacters(source);
    let occurrences = 0;
    let targetIndex = 0;
    while (targetIndex < target.length) {
        const starting_indices = all_character_indices.get(target[targetIndex]);
        if (!starting_indices) return -1;
    
        const match_lengths = starting_indices.map(
            sourceIndex=>matchLength(
                source.substr(sourceIndex),
                target.substr(targetIndex)
            )
        );
    
        targetIndex += Math.max(...match_lengths);
        ++occurrences;
    }
    return occurrences;
};

console.log(shortestWay('abc','abcbc'))
console.log(shortestWay('abc','acdbc'))
console.log(shortestWay('xyz','xzyxz'))
```